# angularjs $http post data objects

Tags: angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

In angularjs using $http method how to pass following data to web API ?.

I have data in the following format. I would like to pass both product and orders to web api.

```
var product : {
  productID : 1234,
  productName: Amamzone Echo,
  DateofPurchase : 12/12/2016
 }

var orders = [   
   { productID : 1234,
     CustomerBought: Nancy,
     CustomerPaid : 323.12   
   },

  { productID : 1234 ,
     CustomerBought: John,
     CustomerPaid : 123.12   
  },
  { productID : 1234,
     CustomerBought: Mark,
     CustomerPaid : 323.12   
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple $http.post like :

```
var orders = [
  { 
    productID : 1234, 
    CustomerBought: Nancy, 
    CustomerPaid : 323.12
  },
  { 
    productID : 1234, 
    CustomerBought: John,
    CustomerPaid : 123.12
  },
  { 
    productID : 1234,
    CustomerBought: Mark,
    CustomerPaid : 323.12
  }, 
];

$http.post('http://someAPI/db1/', orders)
  .then(
    function(response) {
      // success callback
      console.log("Sent Orders Successfully!")
    },
    function(response) {
      // failure call back
       console.log("Error while sending orders")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fix your content :

```
var product = {
    productID : 1234,
    productName: 'Amamzone Echo',
    DateofPurchase : '12/12/2016'
};
var orders = [{
    productID : 1234,
    CustomerBought: 'Nancy',
    CustomerPaid : 323.12
}, {
    productID : 1234 ,
    CustomerBought: 'John',
    CustomerPaid : 123.12
}, {
    productID : 1234,
    CustomerBought: 'Mark',
    CustomerPaid : 323.12
}];
```

Then send them both in an object using **$http** :

```
$http.post('/your/url', { product: product, orders: orders }).then(
    function (response) {
        // success callback code
    },
    function (error) {
        // failure callback code
    }
);
```

Comment: does this mean my web api method will be 
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Product product,[FromBody]Orders orders) {

}

Comment: What do you mean public ? and where are you getting that code in your comment from ?

Comment: The data from the $http will be posted to Web API method defined as below:
[Route("addpartsdata")]
        [EnableQuery()]
        [ResponseType(typeof(ReturnStatus))]
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Product product,[FromBody]Orders orders) { }

Comment: I still don't understand the problem, are you concerned with security ?